# Macbook Pro 2018 - HDMI Arc Support?

Tags: audio, hdmi, airplay

I have a Macbook Pro 15" (2018) model. I just purchased a Sonos amp, and so I'm currently enjoying the quality that this provides.

The issue is however AirPlay can be a bit flaky at times with the audio connection and delay issues on playback, is there a way to connect from USB Type C to HDMI using ARC here possibly if adapters can support this standard? If not I can purchase an adapter to RCA, however I would like to send the audio straight through and let the amplifier handle this part if possible. Thanks.

**EDIT**: This may possibly be an issue with the Sonos amp possibly due to the fact that this worked via my existing HDMI cable/adapter to a Denon AVR via eARC which I later decided to return, however here the HDMI output did not show up in the audio list, however I'm not 100% certain which HDMI specification the Macbook Pro (if not the adapter) is lacking here for the connection to work if this is supported at all.

Comment: The Sonos has AirPlay built-in?

Comment: The Sonos amp does, these are hooked up to a pair of JBL studio 530’s currently. The Sonos one and such however do not unfortunately, which may be what you were thinking of. Sorry :).